# Can I block certain apps from being opened by non-admin users in macOS?

Tags: macos, administrator

I'm on macOS and I'd like to prevent the non-admin user from opening particular apps at all.

In particular, I'd like for system preferences to be unavailable to the user.

I'm thinking that I might use an app like Focus to make that happen. I'm wondering if there are other options. I tried to do this with screen time, but it's problematic for two reasons:

1. The minimum amount of time is 1 minute and not zero minutes which is what I'd like and…
2. Even after the minute and without the screen time password, the non-admin user can still request an additional minute.

My goal is to prevent the app from opening at all for non-admin users.

Answer (score 1):

There are various solutions for limiting user accounts:

- [Locking and Unlocking Preference Settings](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1946752&seqNum=4)
  which requires locking each preferences group using
  *System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General > Lock > Advanced*
  and set "Require an administrator password to access system preferences with lock icons".
  When locked, you need an administrator name and password to unlock and make changes.
- Limit one specific user account by
  [Limit Application Usage in Mac OS X with Parental Controls](https://osxdaily.com/2012/11/08/restrict-applicaiton-usage-mac-os-x-parental-controls/)
- [Disable Access to System Preferences on Mac](https://osxdaily.com/2010/02/11/disable-access-to-system-preferences/)
  for all users, to undo when you or another admin so decide, by using the commands:

  ```
    sudo chmod 000 /Applications/System\ Preferences.app
    sudo chmod 774 /Applications/System\ Preferences.app
  ```

  The above `774` might be instead `775` on some systems, so verify it before.
- You might give these persons only access to the
  [Guest User Account](https://osxdaily.com/2013/03/06/setup-guest-user-account-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score -1):

In general, with a Unix chassis, trying to allow "everything except the following list" doesn't work. A user who knows the Unix command line may be able to do anything in normal reach. (I don't know the exact details of how much Apple has tightened the screws.)

You might revise your question to be what can or can't be done provided your guest does not have IT wizardry skills.

It may be possible that there are things you genuinely can't do from the command line, but as stated you are trying to block access to certain features via GUI, and you are implying that you also want command line skills not to be able to do it either.

But then, on my end it took me a level 3 technical support escalation to deal with a Genius who knew that Macs *have* a command line. So I may be bringing something up that doesn't matter in your case.

Comment: This is not an answer. It would be better suited as a comment on the OP.